# Create a list with jsom returns a failure but actually creates the list

Tags: custom-list, jsom

I am using jsom to create a list. `ExecuteQueryAsync` returns a failure (`onFaildeCallBack`) but the list was created successfully. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<button onclick="createListEmployee()">Click here to Create a List (createListEmployee)</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function ListCreation(spListCreationInformation){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

    //Set the list values
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.set_title(spListCreationInformation.listName);
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(spListCreationInformation.listType);
    listCreationInfo.set_description(spListCreationInformation.listDescription);

    this.olist = oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);
    clientContext.load(olist);

    //Set the field values for the list
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < spListCreationInformation.listFields.length; ++index) {
        console.log(spListCreationInformation.listFields[index]);
        this.olist.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(spListCreationInformation.listFields[index],true,SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
    }

    // create the list and fields
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      Function.createDelegate(this,this.onSucceedeCallback),
      Function.createDelegate(this,this.onFaildeCallBack));
}

function onSucceedeCallback(sender,args) {
    var result = oList.get_title() + ' created.';
    alert(result);
}

function onFaildeCallBack(sender,args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_errorCode());
}


function createListEmployee(){
    //Specify the list
    var spListCreationInformation = new Object();
    spListCreationInformation.listName = "Employee";
    spListCreationInformation.listDescription = "List which contains the Employee information";
    spListCreationInformation.listType = SP.ListTemplateType.genericList;
    spListCreationInformation.listFields = [];

    //Specify the fileds for the list
    var spFieldInformation;
    spFieldInformation = '<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="NewField1" Name="NewField1"/>';
    spListCreationInformation.listFields.push(spFieldInformation);

    spFieldInformation = '<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="NewField2" Name="NewField2"/>';
    spListCreationInformation.listFields.push(spFieldInformation);

    ListCreation(spListCreationInformation);

}

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is doing operations on a list that does not exist yet because you execute the create query async

Comment: Well even without the for loop I do get the same error. As mentioned above even that I get the error the list and the fields gets created. So in general the script is running fine...

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

All I need to do is to change

```
<button onclick="createListEmployee()">Click here to Create a List (createListEmployee)</button>
```

into

```
<button type="button" onclick="createListEmployee()">Click here to Create a List (createListEmployee)</button>
```

So I just added

```
type="button"
```

an everything is working perfectly.